# Importing custom python module with dependencies

Tags: python, import, package, init

I have the following folder structure:
[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnPao.jpg)
└── App/
├── main.py
├── functions.py
└── models/
└── model1/
├── utils/
│   └── file2.py
└── file1.py

inside main.py file:
`import functions`

inside functions.py
`from models.model1 import file1`

inside file1.py
`from utils import file2`

When running main.py I am getting error related to the line "from utils import file2" in file1.py that it can't find utils module

I Have tried the following solutions:
-create **init**. py inside models and model1 folders (tried empty init file then tried to insert import statements in the init file)
-append path to the os
None of the previous techniques where successful, I have solve the problem by importing utils in the main.py but this technique is not very applicable in cases of large projects and may create some circular references and doesn't seems clean way to writing a code.

Answer (score 0):

```
my-app/ 
├─ main.py 
├─ functions.py 
├─ models/ |
    ├─ model1/ │ 
        ├─ utils/ │ 
            ├─ file2.py | 
        ├─ file1.py |
```

Based on this information, it looks like you can use `import utils.file2` because they are in the same directory.

Comment: I have added an image for the files structure instead of text (I don't know wy the text messed up despite it looked neat before posting), and my file structure differs from the one you gathered from the edits

Comment: The structure looked bad because Stack Overflow doesn't respect newlines. Putting it into a code block makes it work.